# Processing one XML document several times

Tags: haskell, hxt

The usage of the Haskell package hxt is still a little wonder for me. Especially the Arrow notation and the resulting types are a magic.

I could not manage the following till now: I want to process a XML file which has mainly two parts. One keeps the definition of objects, the second the usage/purpose of the objects. First I want to write some hxt processing to get Haskell data structures on the part1, after that process part 2 and finally combine both data structures read in the real logic of the program.

Processing the file is now fine in general thanks [the arrows tutorial](http://www.vex.net/~trebla/haskell/hxt-arrow/lesson-0.xhtml). But I would like to have now one do notation doing the three steps: Read the document (lazy), process the resulting structure one time with the first processor and then process the same structure again with the second processor. What I do not want is to call "readDocument" twice as in the following example.

```
import Text.XML.HXT.Core
import Data.Char(toUpper)
import Data.Tree.NTree.TypeDefs

play filename = do 
                  results <- runX (getAllAddresses filename) 
                  results2 <- runX (getAllAddressesUsages filename) 
                  print results 
                  print results2 



getAllAddresses :: FilePath -> IOSArrow XmlTree [(String,NTree XNode)]
getAllAddresses filename =
    readDocument [withValidate no] filename >>>
    getChildren >>>
    isElem >>> hasName "main" >>>
    getChildren >>>
    isElem >>> hasName "part1" >>>
    getChildren >>>
    isElem >>> hasName "address" >>>
    listA(getAddress)                 -- create a list for each variable, so use listA



getAddress :: IOSArrow XmlTree (String,NTree XNode)
getAddress =
    getChildren >>>
    isElem >>>
         (
          neg ( hasName "location") >>>   -- all elements being no "location"
          getName &&& (getChildren)       -- get the name and the value for each element
         ) 
    <+>     
    ( 
      hasName "location" >>>              -- work on all nodes within the  "location" subcontainer
      getChildren >>> 
      isElem >>>
      ( getName &&& (getChildren) )       -- get the name and the value for each element
     )




getAllAddressesUsages :: FilePath -> IOSArrow XmlTree [(String,NTree XNode)]
getAllAddressesUsages filename =
    readDocument [withValidate no] filename >>>
    getChildren >>>
    isElem >>> hasName "main" >>>
    getChildren >>>
    isElem >>> hasName "part2" >>>
    getChildren >>>
    listA(getAddressUsagePurpose2)                 -- create a list for each variable, so use listA

getAddressUsagePurpose2 :: IOSArrow XmlTree (String,NTree XNode)
getAddressUsagePurpose2 =
    hasName "use_obj-names_for_purpose_2" >>>            -- work on all nodes with usage 2
    ( getName &&& (getChildren) )                        -- get the name and the value for each element
```

Example data:

```
<main>
 <part1>
  <address>
    <obj-name>one</obj-name>
    <name>peter 1</name>
    <street>streetname 1</street>
    <location>
      <country>Germany</country>
      <state>Baden Wuerttemberg</state>
   </location>
   </address>
  <address>
    <obj-name>two</obj-name>
    <name>peter 2</name>
    <street>streetname 2</street>
    <location>
      <country>Germany</country>
      <state>Nordrhein Westfalen</state>
      </location>
   </address>
 </part1>
 <part2>
   <use_obj-names_for_purpose_1>
     <obj-name>two</obj-name>
   </use_obj-names_for_purpose_1>
   <use_obj-names_for_purpose_2>
     <obj-name>two</obj-name>
   </use_obj-names_for_purpose_2>
 </part2>
</main>
```

So the formal question is:

How does the monadic do in the function play look like in order to get something like this:

```
readXmlDocument :: String -> IOSArrow XmlTree (NTree XNode)
readXmlDocument filename = readDocument [withValidate no] filename

play filename = do 
             document <- readXmlDocument filename
             allAddresses <- getAllAddresses document
             allPurposes <- getAllAddressesUsages document
             result <- processLogics allAddresses allPurposes 
             print result
```

How do I get from Monads to Arrows, back to Monads, further down to plain data and back to Monads.

And why do I do that how?

Answer (score 1):

One solution to the problem is the following:

Use the Arrow language extension and use a "proc" expression to process a document read in one function in two processor paths. The result is combined in a tuple. Still this tuple contains two Arrows which need to be run. This is done by two applications of the runX function.

Still I do not exactly know if the file is loaded one or two times by this construct once bot results get combined in a following computation.

```
{-# LANGUAGE Arrows #-}

import Text.XML.HXT.Core
import Data.Char(toUpper)
import Data.Tree.NTree.TypeDefs


play filename = (runX addresses, runX usages)
    where (addresses,usages)=(analyseXml (readXmlDocument filename))

analyseXml :: IOSArrow XmlTree (NTree XNode) -> (IOSArrow XmlTree [(String,NTree XNode)],IOSArrow XmlTree String)
analyseXml = proc document -> do 
               allAddresses <- getAllAddresses -< document
               allUsages <- getAllAddressesUsages -< document
               returnA -< (allAddresses,allUsages)

readXmlDocument :: String -> IOSArrow XmlTree (NTree XNode)
readXmlDocument filename = readDocument [withValidate no] filename



getAllAddresses :: IOSArrow XmlTree (NTree XNode) -> IOSArrow XmlTree [(String,NTree XNode)]
getAllAddresses document =
    document >>>
    getChildren >>>
    isElem >>> hasName "main" >>>
    getChildren >>>
    isElem >>> hasName "part1" >>>
    getChildren >>>
    isElem >>> hasName "address" >>>
    listA(getAddress)                 -- create a list for each variable, so use listA



getAddress :: IOSArrow XmlTree (String,NTree XNode)
getAddress =
    getChildren >>>
    isElem >>>
         (
          neg ( hasName "location") >>>   -- all elements being no "location"
          getName &&& (getChildren)       -- get the name and the value for each element
         ) 
    <+>     
    ( 
      hasName "location" >>>              -- work on all nodes within the  "location" subcontainer
      getChildren >>> 
      isElem >>>
      ( getName &&& (getChildren) )       -- get the name and the value for each element
     )




getAllAddressesUsages :: IOSArrow XmlTree (NTree XNode) -> IOSArrow XmlTree String
getAllAddressesUsages document =
    document >>>
    getChildren >>>
    isElem >>> hasName "main" >>>
    getChildren >>>
    isElem >>> hasName "part2" >>>
    getChildren >>>
    isElem >>> hasName "use_obj-names_for_purpose_2" >>>
    getChildren >>>
    isElem >>> hasName "obj-name" >>>
    getChildren >>>
    getText                 -- create a list with objects for each short-name. So use listA
```

Execution can be done as follows:

```
*Main>  snd ( play  "../tmp/haskell/test.xml")
["two"]

*Main>  fst ( play  "../tmp/haskell/test.xml")
[[("obj-name",NTree (XText "one") []),("name",NTree (XText "peter 1") []),("street",NTree (XText "streetname 1") []),("country",NTree (XText "Germany") []),("state",NTree (XText "Baden Wuerttemberg") [])],[("obj-name",NTree (XText "two") []),("name",NTree (XText "peter 2") []),("street",NTree (XText "streetname 2") []),("country",NTree (XText "Germany") []),("state",NTree (XText "Nordrhein Westfalen") [])]]
*Main>
```